# Moving progress bar in html?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I'm programming a progress bar that the bar value would increase. I have used

```
<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
```

and I have also programmed a Java Applet. Well, the applet had problems with security and **some** Mac OS versions don't have a Java SE version yet, so that was out of the picture. Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<title>Get Vander Walls Glue</title>
<head></head>
<style>

body {
    transition: background 10s, color 10s, text-shadow 10s;
    -webkit-transition: background 10s, color: 1s, text-shadow 1s;
    background: #1C8C08;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.75em #08328C;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
body:hover {
    background: #08328C;
    color: #600;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #300, -2px -2px #922;
}
a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #aaa;
}

</style>

<body style="color: #fff; font-family: sans-serif, arial; font-size: 3em; padding: 0; margin: 0">

<h1 class="big">Vander Walls Glue</h1>
<hr>
<a href="http://www.moviemakingman.tk">Back</a><br/>

</body>
<footer></footer>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me and explain? I want to actually hear how it works not that it just works.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. What is it that you're asking to have explained? Is there something specific that's not working properly, or are you saying that it works but you don't understand how it works? In either case, please be more specific.

Comment: sorry @AdiInbar what i was saying is i needed one that its value increases with an animation. and i also wanted to know HOW it works, not that it just works. i figured it out using javascript. http://www.moviemakingman.tk/getgluenow.php

Answer (score 2):

I suggest achieving this with JQuery..

[**Check out JQuery progress plugin**](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#default)

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: 37
});
```

Where value is the percentage in the progress.

I put together a jsFiddle [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/DW33L/1/)!